# How to Create a network folder between ubuntu and windows

Tags: 20.04, shared-folders

if you are see this question again, it means i am posting this again because nobady gave a replay to it

I need help to mount an network folder between Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa (Home network server for me but using normal Ubuntu desktop) and my windows 10 version 1903. I don't know how to configure samba. I also followed lots of YouTube tutorials but nothing worked for me.

Is there is any way by which I can easily share a network folder between Windows (want to share my documents folder with Ubuntu) without complications?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way for LAN file sharing is SMB or Samba (my favorite) you can install this from the apt package manager with `sudo apt-get install samba`. If you already have samba installed than you can follow the Unix SE below and I've had this work on 20+ different linux machines.

and than for simple access I like to refer to this guide from a Unix SE answer
[How to create a Samba Share](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206309/how-to-create-a-samba-share-that-is-writable-from-windows-without-777-permission)

Quote:

> I recommend to create a dedicated user for that share and specify it
> in force user(see docs).
>
> Create a user (shareuser for example) and set the owner of everything
> in the share folder to that user:
>
> `adduser --system shareuser`
>
> `chown -R shareuser /path/to/share`
>
> Then add force user and permission mask settings in smb.conf:
>
> ```
> [myshare] 
> path = /path/to/share 
> writeable = yes 
> browseable = yes
> public = yes 
> create mask = 0644 
> directory mask = 0755 
> force user = shareuser 
> Note that guest ok is a synonym for public.
> ```

Than it's as simple as connecting via file explorer in windows to the Linux's local ip address!

Comment: The samba thing you are trying to refer from is over 5 years ago. I can't find any myshare in the smb.conf file. Even how to acess that using terminal?

Comment: if you read the answer to that post, he says "add" to settings found in smb.conf
that [myshare] wont be in your smb.conf yet. you need to navigate to `/etc/samba/` and open smb.conf with whatever text editor you'd like, I use nano `sudo nano smb.conf` . the answer is one of the most clear and straight to the point answers I've found. If you have anything that stops you from there than google is a good guide